# Using if node on top of two onnx models gives shape inference error

Tags: onnx, onnxruntime

I have two onnx models i exported from pytorch. I named them split.onnx and nosplit.onnx. They make some sort of postprocessing.
I want to have a single ONNX model with 2 computation graphs by using an if node on top of the models. The Then branch is the graph of split, and the Else branch is the computation graph of nosplit. I'm getting this error "Shape inference error(s): (op_type:If): [ShapeInferenceError] Graph has 1 inputs but 0 were provided" and i want to know what i'm doing wrong.
This is the code i'm using:

```
import onnx
onnx_model_split = onnx.load("split.onnx")
onnx_model_no_split = onnx.load("nosplit.onnx")
onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model_no_split, full_check=True)
onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model_split, full_check=True)
assert len(onnx_model_split.graph.output) == len(onnx_model_no_split.graph.output)

graph_split: onnx.GraphProto = onnx.helper.make_graph(
    nodes=list(onnx_model_split.graph.node),
    name="graph-split",
    inputs=list(onnx_model_split.graph.input),
    outputs=list(onnx_model_split.graph.output),
    initializer=list(onnx_model_split.graph.initializer),
)

graph_no_split: onnx.GraphProto = onnx.helper.make_graph(
    nodes=list(onnx_model_no_split.graph.node),
    name="graph-no-split",
    inputs=list(onnx_model_no_split.graph.input),
    outputs=list(onnx_model_no_split.graph.output),
    initializer=list(onnx_model_no_split.graph.initializer),
)
split = onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info(name="split", elem_type=onnx.TensorProto.BOOL, shape=[1])

if_node = onnx.helper.make_node(
    op_type="If",
    inputs=["split"],
    outputs=[o.name for o in list(onnx_model_no_split.graph.output)],
    then_branch=graph_split,
    else_branch=graph_no_split,
)

if_graph_def: onnx.GraphProto = onnx.helper.make_graph(
    nodes=[if_node],
    name="if-model",
    inputs=list(onnx_model_no_split.graph.input) + [split],
    outputs=list(onnx_model_no_split.graph.output),
    initializer=list(onnx_model_no_split.graph.initializer),
)
model_def: onnx.ModelProto = onnx.helper.make_model(if_graph_def, producer_name="onnx-example", opset_imports=[onnx.helper.make_opsetid(onnx.defs.ONNX_DOMAIN, 12)])
onnx.checker.check_model(model_def, full_check=True)
onnx.save(model_def, 'test.onnx')
```

I was expecting a model that could take split a boolean value and an image as input and would output the output of one of the two models. what results is i get this error: "Shape inference error(s): (op_type:If): [ShapeInferenceError] Graph has 1 inputs but 0 were provided"

Comment: Why not combine both models with the additional logic in torch as one `nn.Module` and export it?

Comment: i tried but onnx checks if the split input is used in computation and doesn't find it since its only used in if/else so it removes it when exporting. I get a model that is fixed and that doesn't have split as input